# In mongo db how do I see a very specific data in a collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have user collection and inserted 3 record but want to see the third record only. I did `db.users.find(3)`,  gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `db.users.find().limit(1).skip(2)`

or if you want to see the last inserted document use:

```
db.users.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. but it doesn't work. first one doesn't work.

Comment: what did the second query display? or do you really have 3 documents in users collection?

Comment: Sorry. There was an error on my side. both are right.

Comment: Glad that I could help :) . In that case can you please accept it as the correct answer? ;)